# Multiple cores join query

Tags: solr

My solr version is 4.0
I have a multicore environment with a core for **products** and a core for **availability** records of these products.
The products core will contain detailed descriptions and has about 10,000 douments.
The availabilities core contains up to 4 million documents.

I built a small testset and I'm trying to get results using the join syntax, meant to find alle availabilities of products containing "disney".

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/product/select?q={!join%20from=productid%20to=id%20fromindex=availp}disney&fl=*
```

I get zero results.
Individual queries on each of the cores do yield results.
**Questions**:
1. how should I construct the query in order to get results
2. when I refine my query for filtering for a specific date, what would the syntax be.
for example ?fq=period:"november 2012" AND country:France

country is a field from the product index, period is a field from then availp index.

Results from individual queries: product core

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">1</int>
  <lst name="params">
    <str name="fl">id,productname</str>
    <str name="indent">1</str>
    <str name="q">disney</str>
    <str name="rows">1</str>
  </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="31" start="0">
<doc>
    <str name="productname">DPAZ00 DPAZ00-02 DPAZ0002 Disneyland Parijs Hotel Disney's Santa Fe</str>
    <str name="id">44044</str></doc>
</result>
</response>
```

other core: availp

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">0</int>
  <lst name="params">
    <str name="fl">*</str>
    <str name="indent">1</str>
    <str name="q">productid:44044</str>
    <str name="rows">1</str>
  </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="42" start="0">
  <doc>
    <date name="datefrom">2012-10-01T10:00:00Z</date>
    <arr name="period">
      <str>oktober 2012</str>
    </arr>
    <str name="productid">44044</str>
    <double name="minpriceperperson">209.0</double>
    <int name="durationcode">1</int>
    <str name="id">3890</str>
    <int name="budgetcode">2</int>
</result>
</response>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You should query inventory core (with product as inner index).
This is how the query should be
http:// localhost:8080/solr/product/select?q=*& fl={!join from=id to=id fromIndex=availp}productname:disney

2) You can use the same query syntax above.
http:// localhost:8080/solr/product/select?q=period:november&fl={!join from=id to=id fromIndex=availp}productname:disney AND country:France 
You can remove productname from above if not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried by changing the **fromindex** to **fromIndex** (uppercase **I**)?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Adventures with Solr Join](http://mullingmethodology.blogspot.com/2012/03/adventures-with-solr-join.html), the query look like this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/parents/select?q=alive:yes AND _query_:"{!join fromIndex=children from=fatherid to=parentid v='childname:Tom'}"
```

It should be works